# Calling generic extension method with constraints

Tags: c#, generics

I have a model class with two properties of different types - `SourceData`, `DestinationData`. These properties holds instances of similar classes (in different namespaces) that I need to compare manually and display differences.

I would like to create generic extension method `IsSame` for this problem, so I could write simply:

```
// SourceData: x => ..., DestinatinData: y => ...
var nameIsSame = model.IsSame(x => x.Name, y => y.Name);
var ageIsSame = model.IsSame(x => x.Age, y => y.Age);
...
```

I prepared sample with this scenario but I can't write the method `IsSame` that could be called simply like above. I have to specify all type for generic method call.

```
public interface ISource 
{ }

public interface IDestination 
{ }

public class SourcePerson : ISource 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class DestinationPerson : IDestination 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public abstract class DetailViewModel<TSource, TDestination> 
    where TSource : ISource
    where TDestination : IDestination
{
    public TSource SourceData { get; set; }
    public TDestination DestinationData { get; set; }
}

public class PersonDetailViewModel : DetailViewModel<SourcePerson, DestinationPerson>
{ }
```

Now I have model class of type `PersonDetailViewModel` that implements abstract class `DetailViewModel<>`. I thought that following implementation of method `ExtensionMethods.IsSame` should be called simply by giving instance of `PersonDetailViewModel` that might be recognized because of constraints.

```
public static class ExtensionMethods 
{
    public static bool IsSame<TModel, TSource, TDestination, TValue>(this TModel model, Func<TSource, TValue> sourceProperty, Func<TDestination, TValue> destinationProperty)
        where TModel : DetailViewModel<TSource, TDestination> 
        where TSource : ISource
        where TDestination : IDestination
    {
        if (model.SourceData == null) {
            return (model.DestinationData == null);
        }

        if (model.DestinationData == null) 
            return false;

        return Equals(sourceProperty(model.SourceData), destinationProperty(model.DestinationData));
    }
}
```

However when I try to call the extension method I have to specify all the types even though the compiler should know then all.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var model = new PersonDetailViewModel
        {
            SourceData = new SourcePerson { Name = "Karel Gott", Age = 72 },
            DestinationData = new DestinationPerson { Name = "Karel Engles", Age = 72 }
        };

        Console.WriteLine(model);
        Console.WriteLine();

        //var nameIsSame = model.IsSame(x => x.Name, y => y.Name); // doesn't work :-(
        var nameIsSame = model.IsSame<PersonDetailViewModel, SourcePerson, DestinationPerson, string>(x => x.Name, y => y.Name);
        Console.WriteLine("Name is same: " + nameIsSame);

        //var ageIsSame = model.IsSame(x => x.Age, y => y.Age); // doesn't work :-(
        var ageIsSame = model.IsSame<PersonDetailViewModel, SourcePerson, DestinationPerson, int>(x => x.Age, y => y.Age);
        Console.WriteLine("Age is same: " + ageIsSame);

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit ...");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}
```

**Notice for all:** Please don't write me, that I should compare equality differently. I used here method IsSame just for simplicity. The method works well and the code inside should do something else. I just need to call it without explicitly defined types. In my opinion the compiler should know them all from constrains.

In this scenario I used classes PersonDetailViewModel, SourcePerson, DestinationPerson ... but in my application there are plenty of classes like this. The TSource and TDestination doesnt have same code inside, and the properties should have different names. Imagine that I want to compare properties in these classes:

```
public class SourceCompany : ISource {
  public int CompanyId { get; set; }
  public string NameTradeRegister { get; set; }
  public string AddressStreet { get; set; }
  public string Town { get; set; }
}

public class DestinationCompany : IDestination {
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string StreetName { get; set; }
  public string City { get; set; }
}

var idIsSame = model.IsSame(x => CompanyId, y => y.ID);
```

**Ok, I found the solution.** The extension method should avoid TModel and instead it can declare DetailViewModel.

```
public static class ExtensionMethods 
{
    public static bool IsSame<TSource, TDestination, TValue>(this DetailViewModel<TSource, TDestination> model, Func<TSource, TValue> sourceProperty, Func<TDestination, TValue> destinationProperty)
       where TSource : ISource
       where TDestination : IDestination
    {
        if (model.SourceData == null) {
            return (model.DestinationData == null);
        }

        if (model.DestinationData == null)
            return false;

        return Equals(sourceProperty(model.SourceData), destinationProperty(model.DestinationData));
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you need an extension method? What code duplicate do you want to remove? Why simple call to Equals( x.Age, y.Age ) or x.Age == y.Age doesn't suit?

Comment: No it doesn't, SourceData or DestinationData should be null. You can see that I check it in the extension method.

Comment: Well than just check x and y before doing any field comparison. if one of them is null and other is not than obviously you shouldn't call any comparison methods and x and y should be considered not equal. In your code you're trying to compare x and y with null on every property comparison which is a bit not effective.

Comment: Why do you even have this class structure? There should just be a `Person` class. There is no need for `SourcePerson` and `DestinationPerson`. That and the need for an equality extension method make it look like you are way overcomplicating your program.

Comment: Can you declare an IModel interface, to be implemented by DetailViewModel<TSource, TDestination>, and use that one as constraint for TModel (or avoid that constraint at all)? You could probably rewrite the extension method as IsSame<TModel, TValue>(this TModel model, Func<SourcePerson, TValue> sourceProperty, Func<DestinationPerson, TValue> destinationProperty).

Comment: siride: if you have read the question, I wrote that SourceData and DestinationData are similar but not same class. These classes are from diferent namespaces, the content should completely different. I just know that there are properties with similar meaning (can have diferent names).

Comment: Rubidium-37: I can't create the extension method with explicit types SourcePerson and DestinationPerson. It needs to be generic because I use it with several classes. There is only condition, that all those classes are derived from DetailViewModel<TSource, TDestination>